# Where can I find the machine readable version of Drupal field widget types?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

Where/how can I find the machine-readable versions of field widget types in Drupal? Specifically, I'm looking for the machine-readable name for the "Pop-up Calendar" widget that comes with the "Date" module.

https://drupal.org/node/1455576 details the widget types included in the "Date" module, but not the machine-readable name. I'm trying to use this "Pop-up Calendar" widget type in a module that I'm writing, but am not sure what to put in the mymodule.install field instance  widget type. Is there a standard for deriving the machine-readable from the human-readable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The machine name is *date_popup*. The widget is defined in function `date_popup_element_info()`.

You can find machine names of other widgets by searching for implementations of `hook_element_info()`.